# How to automate django_haystack's rebuild_index command on production or live

Tags: django, django-views, django-haystack

I have used Django_Haystack with Whoosh for effective search on an application I worked on, which worked fine for what I need it for.

To build index on development mode, Django_Haystack documentation advised to run the following command:

> python manage.py rebuild_index

However, after deploy, I figured out that all new details input to that site are not indexed and they fall out of search because there is no measures that automatically build those details into index.

Kindly assist me, how do I automate django_haystack's building index on production such that new details gets indexed automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `HAYSTACK_SIGNAL_PROCESSOR` setting. By setting it to the real time processor, the index will be updated when an instance of in indexed model is updated, created, or deleted.

```
HAYSTACK_SIGNAL_PROCESSOR = 'haystack.signals.RealtimeSignalProcessor'
```